# I want to make my array unique in php

Tags: php, arrays

please look at below output

```
[
    {
        "id": "8",
        "title": "windows",
        "subtitle": "win"
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "title": "windows",
        "subtitle": "win"
    }
]
```

I only want to display

```
[
    {
        "id": "8",
        "title": "windows",
        "subtitle": "win"
    }
]
```

how can i do this?
I have tried array_unique() but it is not giving me proper results.

Thanks in advance! please help me.

Comment: Please show us your attempts also: *but it is not giving me proper results* What does that mean? What results did you got?

Comment: no new questions , just variations